# Inputting data from text as array

Tags: python, arrays, text

Hello everyone,

I have a text file which has the data in the following format:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,9,0,0,0,0,2,8,13,47,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,139,11,1,0,0,4,8,44,139,14,4,1,1,30,45,80,139,34,28,0,0,7,34,117,43,0,0,0,0,0,5,40,139,78,9,0,0,0,12,100,139,121,42,4,1,6,7,16,122,101,117,22,13,4,1,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,9,33,7,0,0,0,0,42,87,139,20,2,0,0,0,6,95,83,9,5,8,39,73,13,45]
```

That is each line is a sample of 128 dimension and likewise, there are 50k samples throughout my text file.

I am performing K-Means clustering for the above given format of data. When I input the data directly, it works perfectly fine in the following code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
import numpy

data = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,9,0,0,0,0,2,8,13,47,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,139,11,1,0,0,4,8,44,139,14,4,1,1,30,45,80,139,34,28,0,0,7,34,117,43,0,0,0,0,0,5,40,139,78,9,0,0,0,12,100,139,121,42,4,1,6,7,16,122,101,117,22,13,4,1,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,9,33,7,0,0,0,0,42,87,139,20,2,0,0,0,6,95,83,9,5,8,39,73,13,45]]   



mbkm = MiniBatchKMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=8, batch_size=100, n_init=10, max_no_improvement=10, verbose=0)
mbkm.fit(data)
mbk_means_cluster_centers = mbkm.cluster_centers_

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
print mbk_means_cluster_centers
```

But when I use this code

```
f = open("sample_input.txt", "r")
out = f.readlines()
for line in out:
    print line
```

To read the contents from the text file into array format, it is failing and I am getting the error "Value Error: Could not convert string to float".

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. Please suggest me a better way to get the code running. Thanks in advance!

PS: I am coding in python 2.7 in ubuntu platform.

Comment: The line looks enough like Python, you could probably just do "eval(line)" and get a nice array of ints.

Comment: You might be able to get what you want by decoding each line as a json string, as that format should be consistent with the json list type. Something like `import json; line_list = json.loads(line);`

Answer (score 0):

I must preface this by saying that storing data in a text file as a code representation of an array is a bad idea. If you can, store your data in a serializable format like CSV or JSON.

What's happening is that you're reading the line and it's in a string format, not an array format. When you iterate over the string (String is still an enumerable), it's getting each letter, but your code then complains about not being able to use that string because it expects a float.

If you **REALLY** need to read that file in that format and you trust the origin of the file, try doing this.

```
f = open("sample_input.txt", "r") 
out = [eval(arr) for arr in f.readlines()]
```

Note that this will also execute code within that file, so make sure you trust the origin of the file.

My python experience is limited, so there might be a safer way of doing this. Next time, use a CSV formatted file for data.

Comment: That command is working for a limited lines of input. For 50k lines of input, I am getting the "setting an array element with sequence" error. Am I  doing something wrong? I even tried out the code specified by Chris and even that is showing me a different error. Please help. Don't know to how to run the file. I have another data with 0.3 million lines :/

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate Moox's point, it would probably be a good idea to use csv to store this information. You can then use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse the file.

Avoiding eval is also a good idea. You can do something like this to parse the data in its current format -

```
def line_to_list_of_ints(line):
    # Split each line on commas and convert to an int
    return [int(item) for item in line.split(',')]

with open("sample_input.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f] # Remove new lines / whitespace
lines = [line[1:-1] for line in lines] # Remove square brackets from each end
lines = [line_to_list_of_ints(line) for line in lines] # Convert the line to a list of integers
```

If you were using a csv file it could be simplified to something like this -

```
import csv

with open("sample_input.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = []
    for line in reader:
        lines.append([int(item) for item in line])
```

Comment: don't call realines unless you want a list, just iterate over the file object

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're absolutely right, I've updated my answer.

Comment: you can also make it a generator object and use a single list pass `line_to_list_of_ints(line[1:-1]) `

Comment: or simply `lines = [line_to_list_of_ints(line.rstrip()[1:-1]) for line in f] `

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

If you have a single array in the file:

```
from ast import  literal_eval

with open("sample_input.txt") as f:
   out = literal_eval(f.read())
   for line in out:
       print line

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...............
```

For multiple arrays:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       print literal_eval(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in `mydata.txt`...

```
% sed '1idata=[ 
s/$/,/;$a]' < mydata.txt > mydata.py
```

creates a python module that you can import in your program

```
from mydata import data
```